# Using \nocite{*}, Want to exclude specific journal articles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm using `\nocite{*}` at the end of my dissertation to print a bibliography of all secondary sources that are relevant to my thesis. But I want to suppress from my bibliography a few newspaper articles that I quote in my conclusion but are otherwise insignificant. I know I could manually list the cite keys I want to  print, but to type that list out manually would take forever. Is there a way to automatically create a list of all my cite keys and then just delete the few that I want to suppress? Or is there a way to maintain the `\nocite{*}` command but create an exception for the entries I want suppressed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please include a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: In case all entries to be excluded are of a certain type, you could do `\printbibliography[nottype=⟨entrytype⟩]{...}`. Same works for keywords or categories. See the biblatex user guide, section `3.7.2 The Bibliography` for more information.

Comment: I'm with samcarter on this one, but `grep @ bibliography.bib | grep -v = | grep -v '\\@' | sed 's/@.*{//g' > ~/output.cite` captures all (it seems) my entries in a `.bib` file over 3000 entries strong while omitting lines that happen to have a `@` sign (e.g., `\@`) in lines other than the entrykey lines.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunate you did not give much information to work with. If all the entries you want to exclude would be of a common entry type, the problem is really easi, just use

```
\printbibliography[nottype=⟨entrytype⟩]
```

to exclude them. If this is not applicable, there are some other ways, for example you could add all the articles, you want to exclude, to a `category`, let's call it "boring":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {TitleA},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@book{keyy,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {TitleB},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{boring}
\addtocategory{boring}{keyy}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[notcategory=boring]

\end{document}
```

[image]